# Can I run a process from my process without becoming its parent?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, windows-shell

I have a somewhat strange request. Let me explain. I recently [run into an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30430394/843732) when I needed to display my screensaver's configuration window by running the following command:

> "C:\Windows\System32\mysvr.scr" /c

The problem is that my parent GUI application that calls it runs with [High Mandatory Integrity Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625962.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), or `S-1-16-12288`, and due to this, when I run the following command via `CreateProcess` API the screensaver configuration (evidently?) tries to communicate with my app and fails because of its high integrity level.

So I'm trying to bypass this by having some other process run this command for me. I looked into possibly using [RunDll32](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164787) but I don't know an API that I can use through it to start a process.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is this really a different question than the other one?  Seems like you could just edit that one to explain what you're hoping might work.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: I'm not exactly sure if this is the solution to that question. I want to try this first.

Comment: PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS

Comment: @HarryJohnston: That looked like a very promising idea. I implemented this approach: http://winprogger.com/launching-a-non-child-process/ but it made no difference. The screensaver configuration process can somehow know that my process started it. The reason I know this is by the way its window is aligned to my window, or to Windows Explorer if I run the command line I gave in my OP from there. There must be something else...

Comment: @eryksun: Yes, his solution answers my question. Harry: Why don't you post it as an answer and I'll mark it. It's an interesting flag that I wasn't aware of.